ApolloGraphQL set up with TypeScript not working in a NextJs project
I am trying to set a graphql server using apollo in my nextjs project but I am getting this error when i run npm start
> playground@0.1.0 start
> npm run compile && node ./dist/index.js


> playground@0.1.0 compile
> tsc

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/macbook/playground/dist/index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

This is my tsconfig.json file:
{

  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "es2020"],
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "target": "es2020",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "noEmit": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}


this is my package.json file:
{
  "name": "playground",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "start": "npm run compile && node ./dist/index.js",
    "lint": "next lint"

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.10.4",
    "@apollo/server": "^4.10.4",
    "apollo-server": "^3.13.0",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "next": "14.2.3",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.14.2",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  }
}


and this is my project setup
1
I followed the apollo docs for typescript but had no sucess
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started

That error suggests your build hasn't outputted as you expect. What does your dist folder look like?
